# JavaScript XML set node value

Tags: javascript, xml

How can I set a value to a node

```
var testVal = "some value"
var XML = document.createElement("div");
var Node = document.createElement("ROOT NODE");
var node1 = document.createElement("TESTING-ONE");

node1.appendChild( testVal );                                   
Node.appendChild(node1);
XML.appendChild(Node);

alert(XML.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `createTextNode`:

```
node1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(testVal));
```

Side note: element names cannot contain spaces, so the following is an error:

```
var Node = document.createElement("ROOT NODE");
```